# A full gross number

Tags: real-numbers

I noticed in my Steam inventory [the following card](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/753/371330-Half%20Gross):

> [image: number 72]
>
> ### Half Gross
>
> A full gross is greater than 99, but we can do with half.
>
> <sub>(the image shows the **number $ 72 $**)</sub>

What is a full gross number? Google results just show me the gross bill amount/gross weight etc. terms, but not the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_(unit)),

> In English and related languages several terms involving the word gross relate to numbers involving multiples of exponents of 12 (dozen).
>
> A Gross refers to a collection of 144 items (a dozen dozen items).
>
> A Great Gross refers to a collection of 1728 items (a dozen dozen
> dozen items).
>
> A Small Gross refers to a collection of 120 items.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

A [gross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_(unit)) is a dozen dozen, or 144. It's an antiquated unit.